# How to generate the sequence number based on condition in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to display a New Sequence column value based on the Score 1 or 0.

```
MonthlyDate Score  New Sequence
----------- ------ ----------
2019-08-01   1      0
2019-08-02   0      1
2019-08-03   0      2
2019-08-04   0      3
2019-08-05   1      0
2019-08-06   0      1
2019-08-07   0      2
2019-08-08   0      3
```

I am trying to achieve on of the calculation in my project based on the new sequence value.

I have tried sum(score) over (Order By Date rows unbounded preceding)

```
Case when Score = 1 
 THEN 0
 ELSE (CASE WHEN LAG(Score) OVER (ORDER BY MonthlyDate) = 0 
 THEN 1
 ELSE (SUM(Score) over (Order by MonthlyDate rows unbounded preceding)) 
 END) 
END as NewSequence
```

Comment: Why did you try `SUM(SCORE)`?   `Score` is 0.   The SUM of a bunch of zeros will be zero.

Comment: that's my worst part, I wouldn't do that. please look on my actual ask.

Comment: So new sequence resets to 0 when score=1?

Comment: @Jamiec, The answer is Yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use mysql because the online tool but very similar in sql server.

**[SQL DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qi6onfMKcLLL6H9xzfLiUd/0)**

```
with cte as (
    SELECT *, SUM(Score) OVER (ORDER BY MonthlyDate) as grp
    FROM scores
)
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY MonthlyDate) as new_seq
FROM cte
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| MonthlyDate         | Score | New_Sequence | grp | new_seq |
| ------------------- | ----- | ------------ | --- | ------- |
| 2019-08-01 00:00:00 | 1     | 0            | 1   | 1       |
| 2019-08-02 00:00:00 | 0     | 1            | 1   | 2       |
| 2019-08-03 00:00:00 | 0     | 2            | 1   | 3       |
| 2019-08-04 00:00:00 | 0     | 3            | 1   | 4       |
| 2019-08-05 00:00:00 | 1     | 0            | 2   | 1       |
| 2019-08-06 00:00:00 | 0     | 1            | 2   | 2       |
| 2019-08-07 00:00:00 | 0     | 2            | 2   | 3       |
| 2019-08-08 00:00:00 | 0     | 3            | 2   | 4       |
```

Comment: realize my seq start in 1, you can do `-1 + row_number()`

Comment: I want new sequence should be reset to 0 when score is 1

Comment: did you saw my previous comment? do you really need I update my answer for that?

Comment: Thank you, It works perfectly fine. if you want to update the answer that would be great. thanks again!

Comment: I could, but then also have to update the sql demo and the output :/

Comment: Remember mark the answer as correct using the green tick if solve your problem

Comment: ok .. I will mark it this as an answer then. Have a nice day!

Comment: the [UK version](https://dbfiddle.uk/) has the major 4 RDMS for your future answers :) [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=26da3a6c0ce1f6d75b58503230e7ef66)

Comment: @scsimon I know but doesnt have Text to DDL :(